# QML (Qt) Anchor Tag or Link jump to section

Tags: qt, hyperlink, qml, anchor

I'm looking to do this in QML (Qt). I have a long text, for example terams and agreement, comprised of 100+ lines and want to be able to set a side menu where users can click on the menu items to jump to that particular section in the agreement similar to what is used in HTML with the anchor tag/link in HTML. I read about stackView, ListElement, FocusScope, Anchor, Positioning, etc... in QML/Qt but none seems to be a solution for what I am trying to accomplish. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

I Googled, searched in Stackoverflow, Youtube, Tutorials but unable to find a solution.

Comment: If you can break up your text into multiple pieces, one way to implement it is a ListView of Text elements. Then you can just set ListView's currentIndex property, and the appropriate section will scroll into view.

Comment: Also note that QML Text objects supports "[rich text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html)" which is a subset of HTML, so maybe it already has what you are looking for.

Comment: Why not using QWebEngine and just do it with plain HTML sections and hrefs?

Comment: One day I have solved something similar with a vertical tab view and a ScrollView.

Comment: If you use`TextArea` and put it inside a `ScrollView`, you can use `cursorPosition` to scroll `TextArea` to a certain index in the text, such as: `textArea.cursorPosition = textArea.text.indexOf("anchor text")`. However, unfortunately, this does not work well with `RichText`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use listview in qml where you should define every content(paragraph) as an element then you click inside you will go to your section .
take a look of move property